# alert() method not resulting in window.focus on modern browsers

Tags: javascript

Whenever I used to call javascript alert method, it resulted in automatically focus to the window it was called in, but in modern browsers like Firefox 11 this is not the case. How do I achieve the automatically window.focus with modern browsers, since alert is very important in my application because its a stock alert.

Comment: so write your own alert function like `{alert(message); window.focus()}`

Comment: @ocanal - `alert` is blocking.

Comment: @DanielA.White, I don't know that, got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that this would not be possible without breaking out of the sandbox which would be nearly impossible. You are at the mercy of the web browsers and the operating system.

There are some notification APIs out for HTML5, but not currently implemented.