# how to conditionally navigate between slides?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using a basic custom made slider which functions perfectly using jquery.
Now, i want to use "next" and "prev" function in the slider only once, second time when a user clicks the link it scrolls somewhere in the page. i have worked out a code which looks like this:

```
var position = 0;

    $('#control_prev').click(function () {
            if (position > 0) {   ///if user is on second slide allow him back to default slide . (0 is the default slide)
            moveLeft();
            position -= 1;
        }
    else if(position = 0){  /// if user tries to go to previous while on default slide nagivate him to home section. 
            $('.control_prev').attr('href', '#home');
            $('.control_prev').addClass( "secondary url" );
            position -= 1;
        }
        alert(position);
    });

    $('#control_next').click(function () {
        if (position = 0) { // if a user tries to view second slide while on default slide we allow him.
        moveRight();
        position += 1;
        }
        else if(position > 0){ // if a user is on second slide and wants to go next slide we navigate him to a different section.
            $('.control_next').attr('href', '#business-events');
            $('.control_next').addClass( "secondary url" );
            position += 1;
        }
        alert(position);
});
```

The i am using alert() to check the position value but the value is 0 all the time.
is it a problem with declaring variable or do you see a flaw in the logic itself?
Please suggest me a way i can solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

-Cheers
-Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with conflating value assignment (done with the single equal sign operator `=`) and equivalence comparison (done with the double equal sign operator `==`). You are using `if(position = 0)`, which will **always return false**. Instead, use `==`: `if(position == 0)`.

p/s: It is usually recommended that you use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`, as the [latter will break JS execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745716/why-does-alert-break-code-execution).

Comment: just a little update "always return false" as it is 0.

Comment: @OnurTOPAL Thanks! I stand corrected — had a minor brainfart ;)

Comment: Thanks, it helped alot. i had to change a lot of tings. the code now looks like this
http://chopapp.com/#x56769d1

still some bugs, but it works as of now :) thanks alot